# Why does this R loop get iteratively more cumbersome?

Tags: r, performance, loops

**Some background:** I am interested in comparing results on a nurse-administered test to patients' most-recent bedside vitals, measured electronically:

- I have one dataset of nurse-administered tests that includes a datetime for when the test was administered.
- Additionally, I have a second very large (~1B rows) dataset of patient vitals with their own datetimes.

My computing resources are limited, so I am interested in writing a nested loop that, for each nurse-administered test (outer loop): 1) Reads in a chunk of the vitals data (inner repeat loop), 2) Checks for data pertaining to the patient the test was administered to, 3) Isolates the row of vitals data with the closest datetime to the nurse test datetime, and 4) Writes the row out to a file.

```
##ned2 is the nurse test data

for(i in 1:nrow(ned2)){

##'index' tracks the current chunk# of the large datafile, 
##'i' is the row number of the smaller datafile we are currently working with

t <- 999999999
temp <- NULL
ned3 <- ned2[i,]
y <- Sys.time()
index <- 0

repeat{

##Read in a piece of the large file; as 'index' increases, skips and reads the next chunk

  vitalchunk <- read.delim(file, header = F, sep = "|", fill = T, nrows = chunksize, skip = chunksize*index, col.names = vitals_colnames)

##Get rid of some useless rows, also restricts vitals data
##to rows having the same 'VISIT_ID'

  vital <- vitalchunk %>% 
  filter(OBSERVATION_TEXT == "HR", KIDS_VISIT_ID == ned3$KIDS_VISIT_ID)


##If, after filtering, there's nothing to match, skip to the next chunk  

  if(! nrow(vital) > 0){
    index <- index + 1
  } else{

##Otherwise, find the row in the current chunk of the large datafile whose datetime 
##is closest to that of the 'i'th row       

  ned3$indices <- sapply(ned3$TAKEN_DTM, function(d) which.min(abs( as.POSIXct(vital$CENSUS_MINUTE_DTM) - as.POSIXct(d, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))))
  vital$indices <- 1:nrow(vital)

##match them      

  z <- merge(ned3, vital, by = c("KIDS_VISIT_ID", "indices"))

##If the datetime of the matched row is closer than the stored datetime 
##of the previous iteration (starts at t = 9999...), replace it with the current one  

  if(abs( as.POSIXct(z$CENSUS_MINUTE_DTM) - as.POSIXct(z$TAKEN_DTM, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")) < t){
    t <- abs( as.POSIXct(z$CENSUS_MINUTE_DTM) - as.POSIXct(z$TAKEN_DTM, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    temp <- z
  }

##Increase index: on repeat, bring in the next chunk      
  index <- index + 1
}

## If the chunk we just read in was at the end of the document, break the repeat   

if(! nrow(vitalchunk) == chunksize){break}
}

##write out the row into a tab-delimited doc, should be the closest-matched row  
  write(paste(temp, collapse = "\t"), file = "P:/Outcomes/Gabe/NPASS/output.txt", append = TRUE)
rm(vital, vitalchunk, z)
}
```

Sorry if the annotations make it harder to see what the code is doing.

Anyway, my question is about what may be happening behind the scenes of this loop.  When I run it, the first few iterations of the "repeat" loop portion run fine.  However, as the loop continues and later "chunks" of the large file are brought in, it takes iteratively longer to run.  The whole point of this loop is to process the large datafile in chunks because it is too large to read into memory at once, but for some reason each iteration of the loop is longer than the previous one and it eventually takes an intractable amount of time.

I suspect that there may be some object being carried from one iteration to the next, but I have had no luck finding the source of this odd behavior.  I'm not experienced with repeat loops, so is there perhaps something in my code that would fix this issue?  Alternatively, could this be a subtle feature of repeat loops?

Thanks for your help, SO; let me know if there's anything I can provide to help.

Comment: It take time to skip lines because you still need to read the data to know where the lines are. Since we are unable to run the code ourselves, can you give some specific timings with what you are observing?

Comment: There may be reasons you've considered and rejected this option, but you might see better performance (and less cumbersome code) if you put your large data set in a local SQLite db and pull chunks in to R from that (or do as much as you can in db).

Comment: @MrFlick: That seems like the most obvious reason I would be seeing the processing times get longer; the times appear to be get exponentially longer, here are a few examples:
(1) 14s, (2) 19s, (3) 29s, (4) 45s, (5) 40s, (6) 70s, ... (40) 18444s.
Makes me wonder if a package is out there that can skip lines without reading them "behind the scenes".

Comment: data.table's fread would probably be much faster, just generally, also might look at memory mapped files...? (package **mmap**)

Comment: Is that time per `repeat` or per loop of the outer `for`? Seems pretty extreme for just file skipping but that depends on how many columns I guess. It can be faster to pre-chunk the large files into batches of a certain size. But i'm not convinced that's the bottle next. I guess you could just compare the timing with the same code with `skip=0` to see if that's the problem. Might also want to think of processing more than one row of ned2 at a time.